# Android SQLite select statement strange behaviour

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm learning android, so I decided to make a simple SMS app. It goes pretty well, but I encountered a problem which I think **I am** able to bypass, but still, I want to know why it happens.

I'll try not to bother you with redundant code, but I'll edit the question and post more if need be.

**THE STRUCTURE:**

I have a class:

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
```

which handles database operations.

In it, I have the following method:

```
public Contact getContactFromPhoneNumber(String pn) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+CONTACT_TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER+"="+pn+";";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_PRIMARY_KEY)));
        contact.setFirstName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_FIRST_NAME)));
        contact.setLastName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_LAST_NAME)));
        contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER)));
        db.close();
        return contact;
    }
    db.close();
    return null;
}
```

which returns a `Contact` object based on the phone number.

Contact class is a simple class with getter and setter methods for attributes `fistName`, `lastName`,`phoneNumber`,and `id`.

**ANOTHER THING I NEED TO MENTION:**

I am **not** passing some arbitrary String value to the method. The value that I pass is previously inserted in the database like this:

```
public void insertContact(String fn, String ln, String pn) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(CONTACT_FIRST_NAME, fn);
    cv.put(CONTACT_LAST_NAME, ln);
    cv.put(CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER, pn);
    db.insert(CONTACT_TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    db.close();
}
```

So the parameter that I'm passing to the first method is already in the database.

The type of the field in the Contacts table where the phone numbers are stored is `TEXT`.

**THE TROUBLE:**

The trouble is that when the first method is called with some String value as parameter which starts with `0` or contains `+` character (I need `+` character for countries' calling codes) to the method above, it returns `null`.

If the `pn` parameter doesn't start with `0` or contain `+` it works well.

**EXAMPLE:** (results are in comments)

```
Contact c = getContactFromPhoneNumber("123456")  // c != NULL

Contact c = getContactFromPhoneNumber("1023")  // c != NULL

Contact c = getContactFromPhoneNumber("0123")   // c = NULL

Contact c = getContactFromPhoneNumber("+3816035")   // c = NULL

Contact c = getContactFromPhoneNumber("123+123")   // c = NULL
```

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is stored as strings but this select query here...

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+CONTACT_TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER+"="+pn+";";
```

... does not quote `pn` as a string literal. Since it can be interpreted as a number, there's no syntax error but it doesn't match any of the strings with `+` or `0` in front.

To quote string literals in SQL, use `''` single quotes. However, it's better to use `?` placeholders and bind values there, like

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+CONTACT_TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER+"=?;";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { pn });
```